# Cannot install pi-apps

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, pi-apps

> Abandoned post by unregistered user.

So I've recently tried to install pi-apps using:

```
git clone https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps
```

and it cloned, but when I used:

```
 /home/pi/pi-apps/install
```

it gave me this error:

```
The command 'sudo apt update' failed. Before Pi-Apps will work, you must fix your apt package-management system.
```

And I even tried manually updating using:

```
wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb
```

but that gave me a 404 not found error!

and of course if I used:

```
 sudo dpkg -i libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb
```

It would obviously give me an error:

```
dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb': No such file or directory
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: `And I even tried manually updating`... manual update would be `sudo apt update`. Run that answering any queries and try to install pi-apps again. It would probably be more effective if you asked the dev direcly on https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps/issues

Comment: Hey Dirk, I just sent this issue to the dev on github.com/Botspot/pi-apps/issues so I hope someone can help me there.

Comment: have you tried to get it from there website?
https://pi-apps.io/install.html

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing:
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Botspot/pi-apps/master/install | bash

Comment: As mentioned in the install instructions: https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps#to-install-pi-apps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turn it off and on again?

```
sudo reboot now
```

and run this again:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Botspot/pi-apps/master/install | bash
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).